# Antd multiselect selected Item color or custom style

Tags: multi-select, antd

I am using this multi select  of antd [Antd multiselect](https://codesandbox.io/s/o5kx47y426)

It is working perfectly fine bt i want to make it like that [Multiselect Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZxv5.png)

Each selected item have specific color.Is this possible with antd multiselect?Antd provides some props like labelInValue but i am confused how to use they have not provided enough detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the color of the selected items by using css or less variables [link to antd instructions for less variables](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme).

To use css, open the node_modules folder, find antd, open the es folder, open the antd component you're using, open the style folder, and then open the index.js file. There you can find the css elements you can modify. Create a css file, change the color attributes on the css elements, and then connect the css file to your javascript/html multiselect.